# LibGDX - Nothing on screen changes when translating camera

Tags: java, android, camera, libgdx, gestures

I'm using a GestureListener to try and create a panning menu, but even though the camera's coordinates are being changed and it's being updated, nothing moves. I think it might be because the stage is drawing relative to the camera but I'm not sure how I would change that.

How I'm going about it:

```
camera = new OrthographicCamera(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
...
gesture = new GestureDetector(this);
        InputMultiplexer im = new InputMultiplexer();
        im.addProcessor(gesture);
        im.addProcessor(stage);

        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(im);
} //end initialization of CustomizeScreen

public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL30.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        stage.act(Math.min(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime(), 1 / 60f));  //0, 18, 31 for layer style
        stage.draw();
        Table.drawDebug(stage);

        batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

        g.batch.begin();
        g.font.setScale(2);
        g.font.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.font.draw(g.batch, "Coins: " + Filer.getCoins(), 15, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - 15);
        g.font.draw(g.batch, message, 0, 150);
        g.batch.end();

        camera.update();
}
...
    @Override
    public boolean pan(float x, float y, float deltaX, float deltaY) {
        message = "Pan, delta:" + Float.toString(deltaX) +
                "," + Float.toString(deltaY);
        camera.translate(deltaX, 0, 0);
        camera.update();
        return false;
    }
```

I've checked for camera coordinates (`camera.position.x`) in the update method, so I know it's actually changing something. But all my buttons remain the same. They are placed in thirds of the screen width (`Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 3`).

Am I missing something, or doing it wrong? I'd think I'm doing it correctly based on everything I'm found on Google.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Stage` class has different constructors. Some of those constructors take a `Viewport`, which contains a `Camera`. If you use a constructor without `Viewport`, the `Stage` creates a new `Viewport` with a new `Camera`.
In that case it will use the created `Viewport` (and `Camera`) for all it's drawing, unless you switch the `Viewport` by calling `setViewport`.
As you don't show, how you create the `Stage` i am not sure if thats the porblem in your case, but if that is the problem, you can solve it by creating a `Viewport` with your `Camera` and passing it to the `Stage` or by changing the `Camera` of the `Viewport` (`stage.getViewport().setCamera(myCamera)`).
Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm currently not using a view ViewPort, no. Thanks, I'll try this in the morning and come back with the results.

Comment: @IHazABone so the problem is the `Viewport` which is created in the constructor. It does not use your `Camera`, if you don't want to create a `Viewport` yourself, you can change the "default" `Viewport`s `Camera`.

Comment: Unfortunately I've been too busy to try it, but I'll get to it in a couple of hours. Thanks for your help and patience :)

Comment: Can't seem to get the Stage to initialize properly with a `Viewport`. Is it supposed to be a specific type of Viewport, or can it just be `Viewport`?

Comment: Nevermind, I got it. Definitely needed to be a proper Viewport. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: I'm glad i could help :) Don't forget to update the `Viewport` inside the `resize` method!